# How can I create an animated vertical page transition in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation

i am looking to animate something like this gif below. The goal is to have two separate with a vertical page transition between them

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjsyO.gif]

```
 <View>
  <Animated.View>
    <Text>Page 1</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePage1Click}>
      <Text>Go to Page 2</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </Animated.View>

  <Animated.View>
    <Text>Page 2</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePage2Click}>
      <Text>Go to Page 1</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </Animated.View>
</View>
```